# How to dynamically instantiate an object from different reference files

Tags: c#, reflection, instantiation

```
using InstrumentA.Interop;
using InstrumentB.Interop;
using InstrumentC.Interop;

namespace SomeProject
{
    class Program
    {
        void InitializeInstruments()
        {
            //I want to be able to instantiate whatever driver I want: (just one of them)
            InstrumentA.Interop.DriverA driver = new InstrumentA.Interop.DriverA();
            InstrumentB.Interop.DriverB driver = new InstrumentB.Interop.DriverB();
            InstrumentC.Interop.DriverC driver = new InstrumentC.Interop.DriverC();
            //or some instrumentD,E, F that users can choose to add.

            driver.Initialize();
            driver.DoOtherStuffs();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the code above, how can I make it so that I can choose to instantiate which class I want, and name it `driver`?

Comment: Do they share a common interface?

Comment: @Rob, yes they do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an interface like this:

```
public interface IDriver
{
    void Initialize();
    void DoOtherStuffs();
}
```

And all three drivers implement this interface, then you can write:

```
void InitializeInstruments()
{
    IDriver driver;
    if (a == 1)
        driver = new InstrumentA.Interop.DriverA();
    else if (a == 2)
        driver = new InstrumentB.Interop.DriverB();
    else
        driver = new InstrumentC.Interop.DriverC();

    driver.Initialize();
    driver.DoOtherStuffs();
}
```